# update field from another select query

Tags: mysql

i am stuck with a simple query if someone can help me on on the same.
i want to update one field with query from another table
the table structure is as follows:-
table stockmain - fields - itemcode, avgcost
table sales - fields - itemid, saleprice, costprice(this field is to be generated with query from stockmain table(avgcost field)
the query is follows:-

```
$qry = "UPDATE sales SET costprice = SELECT avgcost FROM stockmain WHERE itemcode = 'sales.itemid' ";
```

Comment: what the problem you getting?

Comment: @Pratik the query is running but says 0 rows affected

Comment: try to put select query into the () like "UPDATE sales SET costprice = (SELECT avgcost FROM stockmain WHERE itemcode = 'sales.itemid') ";

Comment: @Pratik same thing. i ran the following query exactly.
UPDATE SaleItems_T SET cost = ("SELECT AvgCost FROM StockMain_T WHERE ItemCode = 'SaleItems_T.ItemID' ");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join these two tables to get one data set, and then copy data from one field to another, e.g. -

```
UPDATE sales sl
  JOIN stockmain stm
    ON stm.itemcode = sl.itemid
SET sl.costprice = stm.avgcost;
```